# Order table based on another table

Tags: r, matrix

I have seen many similar threads however, the examples I've seen tend to have a more linear trend to them and as such, do not apply to my problem.

I have a table that looks as such:

```
x1 x2
a  up
k  up
h  up
d  up
p  up
.  .
.  .
```

And another table with the EXACT same entries over x1, where NROW(table1) == NROW(table2), as such:

```
x1 x2
k  up
a  down
d  down
.  .
.  .
```

I want to reorder table1 based off x1 in table2, where the x1 and x2 variables will remain consistent in the output; a for example to still be up.

where the output would look like this:

```
x1 x2
k  up
a  up
d  up
.  .
.  .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match()` to find the positions of x1 from the second table in the first table and re-order. Here's the result in your example. Let's reorder `tab1` by `tab2`:

```
tab1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "k", "h", "d", "p"),
           x2 = c("up", "up", "up", "up", "up"))

tab2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("k", "a", "d"),
                   x2 = c("up", "up", "down"))

idx <- match(tab2$x1, tab1$x1)
tab1[idx,]
```

This results in:

```
  x1    x2   
1 k     up   
2 a     up   
3 d     up
```

Comment: This is perfect ! Indexing for match() needs to be done the other way around though

Answer (score 1):

if you want to keep the table2$x1 order :

```
merge(table1,table2,by="x1")


  x1 x2.x x2.y
1  a   up   up
2  d   up down
3  k   up   up
```

and you can choose which column to delete

Comment: Doesn't apply to me, but good idea anyway!! Thanks for the help!